# Criteria for image processing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, criteria, convolution

What criteria can be used to measure an image filtering algorithm?

I’m writing a paper related convolutional image processing, and I’m lacking criteria that can be used to measure an analyse my results. I’ve thought of it’s influence on image quality however I cannot seem to find any convincing equations or criteria for stuff like noise pollution or distortion etc.

Literally any help is much appreciated as I’m running low on time.

Comment: The application you intend to use the algorithm for should give you quality measures.

Comment: Wow thanks, I didn't know that my experiment should give me data.

Answer (score 1):

Image quality is a large field and can be somewhat nebulous because an improvement in one metric can directly cause a degradation in another metric. Like Nico S. commented, quality measurement is based on the application. A human user may care much more about accurate color than sharpness, while a machine vision algorithm may need minimal noise over accurate color.

[Here](http://www.imatest.com/docs/noise/) is a great resource on image noise measurements and equations.

[Here](http://www.imatest.com/docs/sharpness/) are some sharpness measurement techniques.

[Here](http://www.imatest.com/docs/distortion-methods-and-modules/) is a link to distortion measurement methods.

Don't just use the methods without reason though, figure out what is important to your application and why, then explain how your algorithm improves image quality in the specific areas that are important. Since you're working on filters, an example closer to your application might be how a Gaussian filter decreases noise. You can measure noise of an image before and after applying your filter. The tradeoff of a Gaussian filter is you lose sharpness since a Gaussian filter blurs your image. If the point of the paper is purely to provide analysis, you can present both quality metrics to show that it improves what you want it to improve, but it takes away quality from another area.

[Here](http://www.imatest.com/solutions/iqfactors/) is one more link to other image quality factors you can explore. Good luck.

Comment: My algorithm increases sharpness of an image with the use of convolution, I’ve noticed that the trade-off is increased noise in the image. In photography there is an indicator called Peak-Signal-to-Noise-Ratio and I’ve thought that it might prove valuable in the paper. However it’s applied to photography and I’m unsure if I should use it for image processing.

Comment: I believe it's normally used in compression quality measurements but I think PSNR could apply here. You can demonstrate how the strength of your filter affects the noise with a bunch of measurements, using the unfiltered image as your control or "signal." This will be an overall measurement of _deviation_ or _change_ from the original image. If you want a simpler method to show how your image gets _noisier_ (which could also be considered deviation or change from the original), you can also take a few standard deviation measurements of flat patches in your image after you've convolved.

Comment: If the purpose of your algorithm is to improve sharpness though, you should also certainly include some measurements of sharpness to prove your filter did what you needed it to do.

Comment: Yeah that's actually a really good idea to develop the paper hopefully it will be enough to fill in the word limit :D